# Gnuplot: Iterate over folders

Tags: arrays, directory, printf, gnuplot, system

I have different folders with datasets called e.g.

```
3-1-1
3-1-2
3-2-1
3-1-2
```

the first placeholder is fixed, the second and third are elements of a list:

```
k1values = "1 2"
k2values = "1 2"
```

I want to do **easy operations** in my Gnuplot script e.g. `cd` to the above directories and read a line of a textfile. First, it shall `cd` to the folder, read a file and cd back again etc.

My first (1) idea was to connect `system` command and `sprintf`:

```
do for[i=1:words(k1values)]{
    do for[j=1:words(k2values)]{
    system sprintf("cd 3-%d-%d", i, j)
    system 'pwd'
    system 'cd ..'
}
}
```

with that the same path is being printed, so no CD is happening at all.
or `system 'cd sprintf("3-%d-%d", i, j)'`
Unfortunately, this is not working.
Error message: `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` 
I also tried concatenating the values to a string and enter it as a path: This also doesn't work:

```
k1values = "1 2"
k2values = "1 2"
string1 = '3'

do for[i=1:words(k1values)]{
    do for[j=1:words(k2values)]{
        path = sprintf("%s-%d-%d", string1, i, j)
        system sprintf("cd %s", path)
        system 'pwd'
        system 'cd ..'
    }
}
```

I print the path for testing, but the operating path is not being changed at all.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: The idea in a given pseudo code is like this:

```
do for k1
do for k2
valueX =  <readingCommand>
make dir "3-k1-k2/Pictures"
for int i = 0; i<valueX; i++
set output bla
plot "3-k1-k2/Data/i.txt" <options>
end for
end do for
end do for
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Why do you want to _change_ to the directory (`cd`) instead of defining the path+filename and read that file?

Comment: See pseudo-code: I want to read a number which is necessary for the third inner loop

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a reason which we don't know yet, why do you want to *change* back and forth into the subdirectories?
Why not creating your path/filename via a function and load the desired file and plot the desired lines?

For example, if you have the following directory structure:

```
CurrentFolder
    3-1-1
        Data.dat
    3-1-2
        Data.dat
    3-2-1
        Data.dat
    3-2-2
        Data.dat
```

and the following files:

`3-1-1/Data.dat`

```
1   1.14
2   1.15
3   1.12
4   1.11
5   1.13
```

`3-1-2/Data.dat`

```
1   1.24
2   1.25
3   1.22
4   1.21
5   1.23
```

`3-2-1/Data.dat`

```
1   2.14
2   2.15
3   2.12
4   2.11
5   2.13
```

`3-2-2/Data.dat`

```
1   2.24
2   2.25
3   2.22
4   2.21
5   2.23
```

The following example loads all the files `Data.dat` from the corresponding subdirectories and plots the lines 2 to 4 (the lines have 0-based index, check `help every`).

**Script:**

```
### plot specific lines from files from different directories
reset session

k1values = "1 2"
k2values = "1 2"
string1 = '3'

myPath(i,j) = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",string1,word(k1values,i),word(k2values,j))
myFile(i,j) = sprintf("%s/%s",myPath(i,j),"Data.dat")
set key out

plot for [i=1:words(k1values)] for[j=1:words(k2values)] myFile(i,j) \
         u 1:2 every ::1::3 w lp pt 7 ti myPath(i,j)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
I want to plot a data set given in e.g. /3-2-1/Data/1.txt. I just want one gnuplot file which operates in the upper directory and reads the data and creates data inside. The reason, why i need to CD and CD back is: I need to read a number which is given in a file and that file is located in /3-2-1/. Reading the value of a line in a .txt file limits the number of data files to be plotted and 3 for loops (looping over k1values and k2values and the time) would be needed, which I couldnt test yet bcs jumping to the folder was not working at all.

Comment: @aeffchen I guess, I still can't follow. I understand now: you want to read a number in a file which is located in /3-2-1/, and this number somehow determines how many (or which) files which are located in /3-2-1/Data/ need to be plotted?

Comment: Yeah exactly! :)

Comment: I added a pseudo code, did you see it?

Comment: @aeffchen yes, I saw it. Sorry, but only after my comment. I'm pretty sure you can also create directories within a loop. As soon as I find some time I will create an example.

Comment: I solved it! I will add my solution soon =)

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution:

```
k1values = '0.5 1'
k2values = '0.5 1'
omega = 3

do for[i in k1values]{
    do for[j in k2values]{
        savingPoint = system('head -n 1 "3-'.i.'-'.j.'/<fileName>.dat" | tail -1')
        number = savingPoint/<value>
            do for[m = savingPoint:0:-<value>]{
            set title <...>
            set output <...>
            plot ''.omega.'-'.i.'-'.j.'/Data/'.m.'.txt' <...>
            }
    }
}
```

`<...>` is a placeholder and irrelevant.
So this is how I finally iterate over the folders.
Within the second `for` loop, a reading command is executed and allocated to a variable which is needed in the third `for` loop. `i` and `j` are strings though, but that does not matter.